# How to let CSS-in-JS work with shadow DOM where there are some elements to append?

Tags: dom, append, antd, shadow, shadow-dom

I am working on antd in wordpress + react using shadow dom. Where the styles tag of the antd is appending on head tag. But I want them to append in the shadow dom. I used the code from antd documentation but this is not working in my wordpress site. Here I am giving example of my consoled element.

```html
<head>
  <style data-rc-order="prependQueue" data-css-hash="b38o0g" data-token-hash="5unovc">
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class^="ant-drawer"],

    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class^="ant-drawer"] [class^="ant-drawer"]::before,
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class*=" ant-drawer"] [class*=" ant-drawer"]::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    :where(.css-z9xyz9).ant-drawer .ant-drawer-close {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-inline-end: 12px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1;
    }
  </style>
  <style data-rc-order="prependQueue" data-css-hash="1vl0t8n" data-token-hash="5unovc">
    :where(.css-z9xyz9) a {
      color: #1677ff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: color 0.3s;
      -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
    }

    :where(.css-z9xyz9) a:hover {
      color: #69b1ff;
    }
  </style>
  <style data-rc-order="prependQueue" data-css-hash="ux9z8n" data-token-hash="5unovc">
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class^="ant-col"],
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class^="ant-col"]::before,
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class*=" ant-col"]::before,
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class^="ant-col"]::after,
    :where(.css-z9xyz9)[class*=" ant-col"]::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  
  </style>

</head>
```

This style tag are appending here in the head tag. How can I append them in my shadow dom?

The js code what I used from antd official website.

```js
import { StyleProvider, legacyLogicalPropertiesTransformer } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const shadowRoot = someEle.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
const container = document.createElement('div');
shadowRoot.appendChild(container);
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <StyleProvider container={shadowRoot} hashPriority="high" transformers={[legacyLogicalPropertiesTransformer]}>
    <MyApp />
  </StyleProvider>,
);
```

But still the styles tag are appending in the head element. I am expecting to append them in my shadow dom.

Comment: Since the 16.4 March'23 release, Safari now also supports Constructable Stylesheets. And you can use them in all modern browsers:  https://caniuse.com/?search=Constructable%20Stylesheets Otherwise ``cloneNode`` the ``<style>`` from the head into **each** shadowDOM

Comment: It's not relevant to `antd`, but `styled-components` have a way to specify a style target inside Shadow Dom: https://www.wpeform.io/blog/render-react-app-shadow-dom-styled-components/

Answer (score 0):

I used antd cdn and had to insert outsider-style elements inside the shadow dom. I just manipulated the cdn code. I used window.shadow || document.querySelector("body"). It worked for me.